# Why does self-signed cert work in Incognito but not regular Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, certificate

I added a self-signed cert to an app. When I access it in the regular Chrome window, it does not offer a "Proceed to..." link under Advanced. However, if I access it in Incognito, I do get a "Proceed to" link. Can you help me understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the **very** first time you hit that URL in Chrome, you were asked that question, and once you answered **yes** saying **I'll trust this certificate** then Chrome no longer asked you this question again.

When you start up in **Incognito** mode, the browser doesn't use any previously saved information so you are asked to *Proceed to the link* **every time** when running in **Incognito** mode.

I hope that explains it.

Similarly, as a web dev, you'll run into this a often.  You'll find AJAX calls fail because your hitting a website that has an untrusted certificate (but the error is cryptic).  It's the most confusing thing until you realize what is happening.   The fix is to open the URL to the website, answer **yes** to proceed to the website, and now your AJAX calls will work again.  Until Chrome decides that it doesn't trust the website again and you repeat the process.

For me it can be weeks before Chrome decides to untrust a website again so by then I've forgotten the solution.  After about 50 times, you catch on and realize the pattern.  At least I did. :-)